# React only allow users number keydown input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have a input field that does not allows user to type numeric value. (A non-numeric or a special character value will not be even allow to be typed).

One of the common approach on SO is the `<input type="number" />`. However, it suffers from two things:

1: The arrow: which I am able to get rid of following another stack post, which is not a problem.
2: The input field still allows negative sigh "-" as input.

I also tried: `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" onChange={this.handleInputToken}/>`

```
 handleInputToken(e){
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value)
  }
```

But this still allows non-numeric input

Is there an existing npm module or library that allows this simple implementation? Since it feels like a very common stuff with form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a typed input component and have whatever logic.

This is very, very basic and not tested but will refuse to accept anything that does not coerce to a number and keep the old value, effectively silently dropping anything bad. it will still accept negative numbers, but you can extend the handleChange to fix it

```
class NumericInput extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ''
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    const value = e.target.value.trim();
    const num = Number(value);
    let newValue = this.state.value;
    if (!isNaN(num) && value !== '') {
      newValue = num;
    }
    else if (value === ''){
      newValue = value;
    }
    this.setState({ 
      value: newValue 
    }, () => onChange && onChange(this.state.value));
  }

  render() {
    const { onChange, ...rest } = this.props;
    return <input {...rest} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/zq5ooml10l

obviously, you can use `static getDerivedStateFromProps()` to keep a `value={}` in sync from upstream and have it as a true 'controlled' component

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was just wanted to know if there is existing tool that does that since it is really common in form data. I guess I will need to build my own component as well. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
<input
  type="number"
  min="0"
  value={this.state.number}                  
  onChange={this.handleNumberChange}
/>

handleNumberChange(e) {
    const asciiVal = e.target.value.charCodeAt(0);
    if (
      !(
        (asciiVal > 95 && asciiVal < 106) ||
        (asciiVal > 47 && asciiVal < 58) ||
        asciiVal == 8
      )
    ) {
      return false;
    }
    this.setState({ number: e.target.value });
  }
```

As soon as you try entering negative number, it will return false and the value won't be set in the input field